# Previews are not working when sharing URLs

Tags: share, preview, facebook-sharer

When sharing a link from my blog it used to provide a preview. However, now when I share a link the preview does not show up. The site is http://sacandbeyond.com

When I only share the main url above it shows a preview of an old post. When sharing a specific post say

http://sacandbeyond.com/2012/01/11/coachella-2012-lineup-announced/

It never pulls the preview at all. I use wordpress and just recently went to the timeline on facebook.

I've checked my site on the object debugger tool and get back the below, which appears to be ok.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this problem?

```
Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    http://www.sacandbeyond.com/
Canonical URL:  http://sacandbeyond.com/
URL for Likes:  http://www.sacandbeyond.com/

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do (if you have the permissions to do so on your blog) is add some `og:tags` to the HTML markup of your page.  Facebook needs this information in order to know how to correctly preview your link.
You can read more about the tags and how to use them at this link :
[Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)